# Dependence of work done by battery on circuit elements

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, batteries

The formula for work done by a battery is QV, where Q is the charge transferred by the battery. The battery maintains the potential difference between its terminals through oxidation and reduction reactions. My question is whether the chemical reactions in the battery can gain speed according to the circuit elements, or whether the rate of these reactions is at a constant rate(the work that is done by the battery on the circuit as a whole is constant , and added circuit elements can only utilize the work done by the battery).

Answer (score 2):

The rate of the reactions is determined by the current the battery is driving around a circuit. For practical batteries, the reaction rate at zero current is very close to zero.